# Google Analytics Event working only for sometime

Tags: events, google-analytics, tags, analytics, google-tag-manager

I have set the Google Analytics eventing with the help of Google Tag Manager. What I observed that it will show me results in Google analytics only on day when I'm setting up event and not getting continues result for event below is the screnshot for the same

[image]

Is there any time period for which only events get fired and we will see the result?
What we should do if we want to event tracking work for us continuously.

Comment: While the obvious answer is "no" I think you should provide a little more info (what does your trigger look like, did you remember to publish your changes etc).  This is not enough to help you.

Comment: It seems that you forgot to publish the version of container in GTM.